# How can Adjacency Lists can be efficiently accessed? C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, graph, adjacency-list

I'm following a tutorial on adjacency matrices and lists for graphs. It's very clear how to check whether two nodes are connected in an adjacency matrix.

You just:

```
vector<vector<bool>> adjMatrix(5);
add_edge(1, 2, adjMatrix);
if (adjMatrix[1][2])
    cout << "edge exists";
```

And it's clearly O(1) complexity.

However, I don't understand how to achieve the same with an adjacency list.

```
vector<list<int>> adjacencyList(vertices+1);
adjacencyList[1].push_back(2);
```

If I have multiple vertices in the list, I'd have to iterate and check using if statement if some link exists. This seems absurdly inefficient.

Can someone help me wrap my head around this?

Comment: you can't do that check in `O(1)` time with adj.list

Comment: Oh, why is it even useful then? Is it just a trade off between lower space complexitiy and and time complexitiy for accessing?

Comment: it is useful for sparse graphs - you don't really want to use an NxN matrix to keep a small number of edges

Comment: Thank you, that clears up everything.

Comment: that's useful not only from space but also from computational point of view: in matrix, no matter how many neighbors the vertex has, you still have to check all N cells to get the neighbors

Comment: Also keep in mind that space will always affect time. If you have to do larger allocations, the program has to request more often memory from the system which is terribly slow. Furthermore, normally I store an adjacency list as a `vector<vector<int>>`, if I dont have to delete edges very often. If you only have to delete edges sometimes, the impact of doing that with vector is not that bad (especially when you don't care about the order of your neighbors) and the much faster iteration over a vector instead of over a list is very important to have.

Comment: The operation you want -- checking for an edge between two given vertices -- is not required in most graph algorithms.  Iterating through adjacent vertices is far more common.